# Generics: try pass parametrized collection to List addAll method

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have code (full source code):

```
public class AutoConversionTest {

    @Test
    public void test_autoConversion() {
        Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
        wrapper.setList(new ArrayList<Sub>());
        wrapper.addAll(new ArrayList<Sub>());
    }

    class Wrapper {
        List<? extends Super> list;

        public void setList(List<? extends Super> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        public void addAll(List<? extends Super> list) {
            this.list.addAll(list);  //TROUBLES!
        }
    }

    class Super {}

    class Sub extends Super {}
}
```

**Question**:
Wy error and how to sovle it?

**EDITED**: my error log

```
java: no suitable method found for `addAll(java.util.List<? extends expectations.public_method.experiments.AutoConversionTest.Super>)`
 method `java.util.List.addAll(int,java.util.Collection<? extends expectations.public_method.experiments.AutoConversionTest.Super>)` is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
 method `java.util.List.addAll(java.util.Collection<? extends expectations.public_method.experiments.AutoConversionTest.Super>)` is not applicable (actual argument `java.util.List<? extends expectations.public_method.experiments.AutoConversionTest.Super>` cannot be converted to `java.util.Collection<? extends expectations.public_method.experiments.AutoConversionTest.Super>` by method invocation conversion)
```

Comment: What is your error? We have no idea from your post.

Comment: `List<? extends Super>`. What is `Super` in this case?

Comment: What is Super and what is Sub? Where in the Wrapper class are the two last lines included? We need the code precisely written.

Comment: Super and Sub are hibernate Entities

Comment: java: no suitable method found for addAll(java.util.List<capture#1 of ? extends Super>)
    method java.util.List.addAll(int,java.util.Collection<? extends capture#2 of ? extends Super>) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method java.util.List.addAll(java.util.Collection<? extends capture#2 of ? extends Super>) is not applicable
      (actual argument java.util.List<capture#1 of ? extends Super> cannot be converted to java.util.Collection<? extends capture#2 of ? extends Super> by method invocation conversion)

Comment: Does the question contain a copy-and-paste of your code or just a sample you typed in? It would have to be the latter, which is quite unhelpful, so please try the former.

Comment: I've just placed full source code

Comment: all you need^ full source code and error log )

Comment: Try to parametrize the class with `Wrapper<T extends Super>` and define the lists as follows `List<T> list`. And initilize it with `Wrapper<Sub>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I infer you want the class Sub to extend class Super as:

```
class Super {}
class Sub extends Super {}
```

Even if you write the classes as above, the wildcard prevents you from adding anything to a list, since it serves only for read-only lists. You can probably do your task with the class Wrapper as:

```
public class Wrapper<T extends Super> {

    private List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    void doStuff(){
        List<Sub> al = new ArrayList<Sub>();
        for(Sub s : al)
            list.add((T) s);
    }

}
```

Comment: yeah, but I showed you simplified example. Actualy, Wrapper is a big class that hava a lot of functionality. It will be a bad practice to parametrize it for the sake of list

Comment: With wildcard (?) you cannot add anything to a list. You should decide what exactly you want to do. There is always a "trade-off" when using Generics, they cannot do all at the same time.

Comment: I'll keep in mide. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

`List<? extends Super>` means: a list of some *unknown* type, which extends Super. So, you can't add anything (except null) to such a list, since you don't know the type of its elements. If this was allowed by the compiler, you could add instances of `OtherSub` to a `List<Sub>`, which would ruin the type-safety of the list.

Change the type of `Wrapper.list` to `List<Super>`.

EDIT:

Modified code:

```
class Wrapper {
    List<Super> list;

    public void setList(List<? extends Super> list) {
        this.list.clear();
        this.list.addAll(list);
    }

    public void addAll(List<? extends Super> list) {
        this.list.addAll(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, but I need to proceed both operations:
Wrapper.list = new ArrayList<Sub>(); and
Wrapper.list.addAll(new ArrayList<Sub>())

Comment: in your case I can't proceed setList method

Comment: Copy all the elements from the passed list to the wrapped list in your setList() method.

Comment: In your case I can't even pass ArrayList<Sub> into setList(List<Super> list) method. What did you mean?

Answer (score 2):

`List<? extends Super>` means the list can consume any unknowns as long is it is a `Super` class of a child of `Super`.

Unfortunately, you cannot add an unknown (as the compiler wouldn't match the type of element through some "capture of" rules) to a list, except null.

The best principle is to use the **PECS** principle (**P** roducer **E** xtends, **C** onsumer **S** uper). Seeing your `list` is a consumer, you should have a `List<? super Super>` to consumer unknowns.

Comment: but how in your case I should push Sub-elements in my list?